# Apps Script, difficulty on trigger action when 2 values match

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my code:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive() ; 
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ANULAR') ;
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('PQ') ;

  var todos = sheet1.getRange("D7").getValue();

  var sqlData = sheet1.getRange("P4").getValue();

  var cant = sheet1.getRange("R4").getValue();
  var idpnqsAnular=sheet1.getRange("T6:T20").getValues();
  var idpnqs= sheet2.getRange("A:A").getValues();


  if (todos==true){

    for (var i=0;i< idpnqs.length;i++){

      for (var j=0;j<3;j++){

        var a1=idpnqsAnular[j];//just for control on debugging
        var a2=idpnqs[i];//just for control on debugging
        var isIt=idpnqsAnular[j]==idpnqs[i];//just for control on debugging

        if(isIt){          
          sheet2.getRange(i+1,6).setValue("CANCELADA");         
        }  
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

The basic idea is: I have a list of codes in `var idpnqsAnular` that I wanna delete in `sheet2` when found.

That's why I iterate over idpnqs, and inside that for loop I iterate again over my list of codes. When the value on the ouside loop is equal to the value on the inside loop, in column 6 the value is changed to "CANCELADA" (cancelled in spanish). Problem is, the code never evaluates the values as equal, even when they are.

Here some captures from the debugging:

[image]

Even when `a1` and `a2` (variables created only for this detail on debugging) are exactly the same, the variable that compares them (`isIt`) evaluates as `false`.

Please, if you find the error, enlight my stupidity.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your light reached me, @TheMaster it worked perfectly!

Comment: `[]===[]` will never be `true`. You cannot compare objects or arrays. You need to compare primitives: strings, number,boolean.... `a1` and `a2` are arrays.

Comment: Great! Consider adding a answer if  you think it'll help others or  accept it as a duplicate.